# Should one train/test their 1RM?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, strength-training

I recently watched a video of fitness youtuber talking about him testing his 1RM frequently (about every 6-8 weeks), which would replace one of his "regular" training days. He does that by calculating his 1RM and then trying to lift that with some friends spotting him. Unfortunatly he does not talk why he does that. I won't include the video because it is not in english and doesn't really contribute to the question itself other than giving the context of why I'm asking the question in the first place.

When training in a bodybuilding-like fashion (training for hyportrophy and gaining muscle size), should one test their 1RM frequently? If yes, why? What are the benefits of that (except maybe boosting your ego)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can only speculate on why he in particular chose to do so, but many programs especially those focusing on hypertrophy calculate weights relative to your 1RM. As you get stronger, those numbers need to be updated to reflect strength increases over time.

A major component of hypertrophy training is progressive loading and the lifting the heavy weights required to calculate your 1RM provides an additional environmental factor that contributes to muscular growth